# How do I get a proper mathematical \Lambda when using gfsneohellenic?

Tags: fonts, symbols, greek

I am using the gfsneohellenic for my paper (which is in English). I load it using:

```
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
```

Everything works fine except for capital greek letters! In other words when I use $\Lambda$ instead of using the corresponding lambda in the neohellenic package LaTeX uses Lambda from computer modern!

This is really annoying since computer modern looks quite different from neohellenic and the inconsistency makes my paper look very ugly.

Comment: This does not really seem to be a question. If you want to report a bug, I'd suggest e-mailing the package maintainer directly. You might also want to post to the usenet group 'comp.text.tex' (accessible _via_ Google Groups), as a lot of package bugs get reported there. I'm suggesting this 'question' is closed.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I think it's just the way he's phrased it.

@Hesam: You might want to rephrase this, something like "How do I get a proper mathematical \Lambda when using gfsneohellenic"

Comment: @Brent: Thank you I changed the question accordingly.

@Joseph: As Brent said I did not phrase it correctly. It is not a bug since nothing really goes wrong I just want to tweak the output.

Comment: Please ignore my 'close' vote: the rephrased question is fine. (See discussion on 'meta' about inability to reverse closing votes!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could redefine `\Lambda` to use gfsneohellenic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\CMLambda\Lambda
\newcommand*{\gfs}[2]{\renewcommand*{#1}{\mathalpha{\text{%
  \selectlanguage{greek}\textneohellenic{#2}}}}}
\gfs{\Lambda}{L}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Neohellenic text: & {\selectlanguage{greek}\textneohellenic{L}} \\
  Neohellenic math: & $\Lambda$ \\
  Computer Modern:  & $\CMLambda$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I saved the original Computer Modern `\Lambda` in `\CMLambda`. This way it's still accessible for comparing. Here's the output:

[image]

For convenience, here's the an example font table of gfshellenic:

[image]

I created it using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{gneohellenicrg6r}
\end{document}
```

Replace `gneohellenicrg6r` by `cmr9` to see a Roman table. This might help you to get the correspondence that you asked for in your comments.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this for all capital greek letters at the same time?

PS: It does not work, t turns my English text into greek. I want the capital greek letters in the math mode be neohellenic. I am happy with my English text!

Comment: I've modified the example. The macro `\gfs` should make it easy: just write `\gfs{\Delta}{D}` etc. The text has been greek before because it was just a demo example without switching between English and Greek.

Comment: Now the question is 'why isn't this done by the package itself?'!

Comment: @Stefan that does work in fact I just should find a place to get all the correspondence between the Greek alphabet and English alphabet (I guessed X --> \Xi but the other ones I don't know).


@Joseph yes you would think that should be done by the package itself but it does not which is why I initially termed it a 'bug'.

Comment: @Hesam have a look here: http://www.kfish.org/tech/latex/greek-alphabet.html

Comment: @Stefan I know about the Greek alphabet. I was asking for a list of associations between Roman letters and Greek ones needed in our case (like D <--> \Delta).

Comment: That page shows which Greek letters are typeset using the Roman font, for instance X for a capizalized chi, that's why I've mentioned it for an association. Would font tables help you to associate?

Comment: No it does not work that way for example I use 'X' for \Xi using your method.

Comment: `\gfs{\Xi}{X}` works for me. Try `\gfs{\Xi}{\Xionealt}` or `\gfs{\Xi}{\Xitwoalt}` is you would like to have different designs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the package documentation you should load `cmbright` as well as `gfsneohellenic`. Did you try something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
\begin{document}
\[ \Lambda = \lambda \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I did. After that LaTeX will use $\Lambda$ from cmbright rather than computer modern. The neohellenic package has a very nice looking capital lambda, I want LaTeX to use that one for math.